# python: plotly bar graph using y0 and dy offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I'm investigating using `plotly` to replace some graphing I currently do in `matplotlib`.

I need to control a bar graph to have the bottom and top of each bar start and end at arbitrary vlaues.

In `matplotlib` this is fairly straight forward:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(0.5, height=4,bottom=2)
plt.ylim(0, 8)
plt.xlim(0, 2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The [docs for plotly](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-y0) seem to indicate I can do something similar by using `y0` and `dy` arguments in the `Bar` object like so:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=['x'],
    y0=2,
    dy=6,
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1])
py.iplot(fig)
```

But this just gives me an empty plot?!

[image]

I also tried feeding the above matplotlib object into plotly's `py.plot_mpl()` but this raises `PlotlyEmptyDataError`.

thanks
JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [`base`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-base) parameter for that:

```
data = [go.Bar(
            x=['x'],
            y=[4],
            base=[2],
    )]
```

[image]

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work when using `plotly.offline`? Seems to work fine when using their online service but not when creating something locally.

Comment: Well, that's weird, I don't have IPython notebook here to test it in my computer. Maybe you will find something in the discussion where this feature was implemented: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/80

Comment: @jprockbelly I just tested it, it's not only with you, it's weird, it doesn't work when creating the file locally.

Comment: thanks for letting me know, I might raise an issue on github

Comment: just so you know this was just a version issue, it is fixed in plotly version 2.0.12  https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/794

Comment: I would appreciate if you could have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394506/python-plot-predicted-truth-and-predicted-value-in-the-same-graph